# Can I put in a MySql table the exact time of when inserted a data?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-insert

I'm building a db where I need to know the hh:mm:ss of when I inserted some data in a table, to make it result as a column of the itself table.

Idk if I explain myself good, I'll make an example:

I need a table like this:

```
------------------------------------------
| IDtable | users | passwords | log_time |
| ---------------------------------------|
|    1    | dude  | dudepass  | hh:mm:ss |
------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can store the timestamp when a record was craeted with an auto-initialized column.

```
create table mytable (
    id           int primary key auto_increment,
    username     varchar(50),
    password     varchar(50),
    created_ts   timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

Then you `insert` intoi the table like so:

```
insert into mytable(username, password) values('foo', 'bar');
```

And `created_ts` is automatically initialized with the current date/time as of insertion time.

You can also track the point in time when a row was last *changed* with the `on update` clause:

```
create table mytable (
    id           int primary key auto_increment,
    username     varchar(50),
    password     varchar(50),
    created_ts   timestamp default current_timestamp,
    updated_ts   timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
);
```